# read .env file and convert all lines into an object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to read an `.env` file that [Foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman) is using to read env variables that you might want to have when starting the node server.

I'm using:

```
var path = require("path"),
    _ = require("underscore"),
    fs = require("fs"),
    variables = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, ".env"), "utf8");
```

At this point I have a string containing something like this:

```
NODE_ENV=development
PORT=8080
```

I would like to convert that string into an object so I can read it like this:

```
{
    NODE_ENV: "development",
    PORT: 8080
}
```

I'm not sure how I could do it. I was thinking of Regex but I have no clue how to read line by line. Or how about the type of the variable ? Can I detect if it's a string or number ( I was just thinking to see if there are numbers only it means it's a number ? ) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String.replace` is a primary means for simple parsing:

```
var env = {}
variables.replace(/(\w+)=(.+)/g, function($0, $1, $2) { env[$1] = $2 })
```

To convert numeric values like `8080` to Numbers,

```
variables.replace(/(\w+)=((\d+)|.+)/g, function($0, $1, $2, $3) {
    env[$1] = $3 ? Number($3) : $2;
});
```

Comment: This part `function($0, $1, $2) { env[$1] = $2 }` will run each line I guess and create a property with what I have as before equal and as value what is after equal ( does this also take care of the type ) ?